# SQL Performance on joining 2 scripts ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, performance

I have 2 scripts which are quite complicated, one was written by me personally, another was done 10 years ago. The first script gets necessary id's and executes in around 30 sec, example:

```
| ID | some other info ...
+----+--------------------
| 1  |       ...
| 2  |       ...
| 3  |       ...
| 4  |       ...
```

The second script get's some more complicated data, which is calculated through many sub queries, and executes in around 30 sec, ex:

```
| ID | Computed Info
+----+--------------------
| 1  |       111
| 2  |       222
| 3  |       333
| 4  |       444
```

Now my script1 needs to include some partial results from script2, because the script2 is very complicated it is quite hard to break down the necessary parts, that is why I have tried to left join results of the script2 to the script1 using ID's

```
SELECT TABLE1.*, TABLE2.COMPUTED_INFO FROM SCRIPT1 TABLE1 LEFT JOIN SCRIPT2 TABLE2 ON TABLE2.ID = TABLE1.ID
```

The result I got and also the expected result is:

```
| ID | some other info ... | Computed Info
+----+---------------------+---------------
| 1  |       ...           |  111
| 2  |       ...           |  222
| 3  |       ...           |  333
| 4  |       ...           |  444
```

The problem is that after joining both of them the time of execution is now 20+ min.

I have also tried

```
with table1 as 
             (script1), 
     table2 as 
             (script2) 
select t1.*, t2.computed_data 
from table1 t1 left join table2 t2 on t2.id = t1.id
```

Which resulted in 10+ min. 
I am wondering why such thing occurs, when definitely script1 and script2 separately run in around 30 sec each, but when run together go as much as 10+
Is there another way to accomplish that?

Comment: Have you tried running [EXPLAIN PLAN](https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/TGSQL/generating-and-displaying-execution-plans.htm) on your queries? What's the output?

Comment: @markusk I didn't, should have though about that

Comment: @markusk for the problematic script2 I don't get any result, and get error specifying that there is space quoata exceeded, for the script1 it executed, which column should I pay attention from plan_table?

Comment: The interesting part isn't the individual execution plans for `script1` and `script2` separately, but rather the execution plan for the join. I suspect your problems are caused by a large number of rows returned by `script1` and `script2` combined with no indexes. If you could [display the explain plan](https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/TGSQL/generating-and-displaying-execution-plans.htm#TGSQL94706) and copy the output into your question, that would help analyze your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create temp tables before joın those tables.

first create table **temp1** as select * from script1

and  create table **temp2** as select * from script2

then select your query

```
SELECT temp1.*, temp2.COMPUTED_INFO FROM temp1 TABLE1 LEFT JOIN temp2 TABLE2 ON temp2.ID = temp1.ID
```

Comment: I have researched temp tables a bit, it seems like I will need to define them once, and they will be filled with each session when I need. I am wondering if it is possible to avoid using temporal tables, and do everything within sql query, or at least what is the reason for such increment of time, since script1 implements in x time and script2 in y time, why can't I get perfomance around x+y time?

Comment: can you see the explain plan ? if you join these scripts it has different explain plan. maybe you can try with statement with materalize hint

Comment: I have tried creating temp table for the script, but it takes 20 min to insert the data into the temp table, while simply executing scripts takes around 30 sec, am I missing something?

Comment: you are missing when you run select query it does not bring all data, for example in toad it brings 500 rows so it may be fast but all data is not

Comment: At first I also had similar thoughts, but there are only 600+ rows returned from script2, while script1 returns 45

Comment: as I mentioned above in total, the script1 returns 40+ rows, and script2 600+ rows

Comment: TOTAL ROWS is 600 ? or billion?

Comment: By 600+ I mean somewhere between six hundred and seven hundred

Comment: when you create script1 and 2 tables , select count(*) from those tables returns how many rows?

Answer (score 2):

Last time when I had this kind of issue, I resolved it with a temporary table. I'd created temporary tables with the SCRIPT1 and SCRIPT2 results. Then added indices to the ID columns.

After this, a similar query than yours must execute faster.

This happened on a postgresql server, but the problem's root is the same. Usually an RDBMS can't optimise a subquery/resultset from a PROCEDURE/FUNCTION and cannot use indices on its rows.